# How to split each column value from the given string

Tags: c#, csv

I am trying to split each column value from the string variable. The value is coming from an excel comma seperated file. how can I split each column from each string

```
 string1=    "\"1\",\"Truck\",\"FN60HZU\",\"'WC\",,\"26/03/2022\",\"H2\",\"NEARSIDE OUTER\",\"1\",\"31580225\",\"TRIANGLE\",\"TRS02\",\"14\",\"14\",\"14\",,\"17\",\"5TST001\",\"16:01:00\",\"16:07:16\",\"40:D3:AE:CB:16:EE\""
  string2 =   "\"1\",\"Truck\",\"FN60HZU\",\"'WC\",,\"26/03/2022\",\"H2\",\"OFFSIDE OUTER\",\"2\",\"29580225\",\"FROMWAY\",\"HD919\",\"15\",\"15\",\"15\",,\"17\",\"5TST001\",\"16:01:00\",\"16:07:16\",\"40:D3:AE:CB:16:EE\""
 string3=   "\"1\",\"Truck\",\"FN60HZU\",\"'WC\",,\"26/03/2022\",\"H2\",\"NEARSIDE INNER\",\"2\",\"29580225\",\"GOODYEAR\",\"KMAXD\",\"12\",\"12\",\"12\",,\"17\",\"5TST001\",\"16:01:00\",\"16:07:16\",\"40:D3:AE:CB:16:EE\""
```

Comment: If you open that file in a simple text editor like notepad do you see exactly the strings as above (I mean with \" before and after each comma?

Comment: You find a csv handling framework. There are many. And use it to deserialize and serialize.

Comment: When you are already tried something just show us the code or do you want us to write it for you? ;)

Comment: something like this maybe: 
var columns = string1.Replace(@"\", "").Replace("\"", "").Split(',')

Comment: Perhaps every line in the file has been json serialized - they look like some quoted CSV of data such as `"1","Truck","FN60HZU"` has been run through a serializer line by line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//I know this is a dumb answer (?) lmao, but I've experienced like this before.
        //Just simply replace the current delimiter into new delimiter then split with your new delimiter.
        //This one works for me.

        yourstring.Replace("\",\"", "|");
```

Answer (score 2):

I created function which I used Regex to split csv line accordingly.

```
public static string[] CSVReadlineToArray(this string fReadLine)
    {
        string[] _ReturnThis = null;
        Regex rexCsvSplitter = new Regex(@",(?=(?:[^""]*""[^""]*"")*(?![^""]*""))");

        _ReturnThis = rexCsvSplitter.Split(fReadLine);

        return _ReturnThis;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This program splits your string and writes each column in its own row:

```
using System;
class Program {
  public static void Main(string[] args) {
    var string1="\"1\",\"Truck\",\"FN60HZU\",\"'WC\",,\"26/03/2022\",\"H2\",\"NEARSIDE OUTER\",\"1\",\"31580225\",\"TRIANGLE\",\"TRS02\",\"14\",\"14\",\"14\",,\"17,18,19\",\"5TST001\",\"16:01:00\",\"16:07:16\",\"40:D3:AE:CB:16:EE\"";

    var columns = string1.Replace("\",\"", "|").Replace(",,", "||").Replace("\"","").Split('|');

    foreach(var col in columns)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(col);
    }
  }
}
```

Test it here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0C8nLP

Output:
1
Truck
FN60HZU
'WC

26/03/2022
H2
NEARSIDE OUTER
1
31580225
TRIANGLE
TRS02
14
14
14

17,18,19
5TST001
16:01:00
16:07:16
40:D3:AE:CB:16:EE

Comment: What will happen if cell value includes comma? Like `"\"1,2,3\",\"Truck\""`?

Comment: Was that a requirement in the question? I can't see that any of the example strings have such sub-lists. To handle that would require some more code.

Comment: This handles such sub-lists as well: https://dotnetfiddle.net/XPVlFB

Comment: I fixed it and added support for comma-separated sub-lists.